# An Apex error occurred: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method

Tags: apex

I have started receiving apex exception alerts,

> "Error element myRule_8_A1 (FlowActionCall). An Apex error occurred: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: ECRCalendarCreateHandler.upsertCreateEventIssueOnJira(Id)"

This process was created back in 2018 and has not been modified yet is suddenly throwing this exception.  Unfortunately, I inherited this and have no developer background.  The code for the apex class `ECRCalendarCreateHandler` is below.

```
/**
 * ECRCalendarCreateHandler
 * author: nboyd
 * 
 * -This apex class contains an invocable method to create 
 *  new JIRA tickets upon Major & Approved ECRs
 * -JIRA will handle the creation of TeamUp calendar events
 */
public class ECRCalendarCreateHandler {
    /**
     * CreateECREventIssue
     * @InvocableMethod called from Process Builder 
     * (Update Shared Calendar w/ ECR Event)
     * 
     * @return void
     * @param List<Id>
     */
    @InvocableMethod(label='Create ECR Event Issue')
    public static void CreateECREventIssue(List<Id> ids) {
        for(Id ecrid : ids) {
            upsertCreateEventIssueOnJira(ecrid);
       }
    }
    /**
     * upsertCreateEventIssueOnJira
     * @future (required to make an ansynchronous Web 
     *  service callout) called from CreateECREventIssue
     * -Creates Issue template to create an Event 
     *  issue type in JIRA
     * 
     * @return void
     * @params Id
     */
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void upsertCreateEventIssueOnJira(Id ecrid) { 
        zsfjira.ZCBeans.ApiOptions options= new zsfjira.ZCBeans.ApiOptions();
    options.userImpersonate = false;
        zsfjira.ZC.Issues.setApiOptions(options);
        
        Environment_Change_Request__c ecr = [SELECT Change_Type__c, Pod__c, Region__c, Stack__c, Description__c, Change_Description__c, 
                                             Change_Window_Start__c, Change_Window_End__c, Account__c, Withdrawn__c, SCKey__c, Department__c  FROM Environment_Change_Request__c 
                                             WHERE Id = :ecrid]; 
      
        Account acc = [Select Short_Name__c From Account WHERE Id =: ecr.Account__c];
        zsfjira.ZCBeans.IssueTemplate issue = new zsfjira.ZCBeans.IssueTemplate(ecrid);
        if(ecr.Withdrawn__c == true) {
            issue.addCustomField('customfield_16600','Cancelled');
        }
        issue.setProject(new zsfjira.ZCBeans.KeyIssueFieldValue('SC'));
        issue.setIssueType(new zsfjira.ZCBeans.NameIssueFieldValue('Event'));
        
        issue.setSummary(acc.Short_Name__c + ' (' + ecr.Stack__c + ') ' + ecr.Description__c);
        issue.setDescription('[' + acc.Short_Name__c + ']<br/>' + ecr.Change_Description__c);
        
        issue.addCustomField('customfield_15900', new Map<String,String>{'id'=>determineJiraCalendar(ecr.Department__c)});
  
        string startDate = ecr.Change_Window_Start__c.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss');
        string endDate = ecr.Change_Window_End__c.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss');
     
        issue.addCustomField('customfield_12518', convertDateFormat(startDate));
        issue.addCustomField('customfield_12519', convertDateFormat(endDate));
        
        zsfjira.ZCBeans.IssueUpsertResult iresult;
        if(System.Test.isRunningTest() == false) {
          iresult = zsfjira.ZC.Issues.createIssue(issue); 
        }
        if(iresult != null) {
          if(iresult.hasError()){
          for(String errorMessage:iresult.getErrorMessages()){
              System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,errorMessage);
          }
      }
          updateSharedCalendarKey(ecr.SCKey__c, ecr, iresult);
          System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.INFO, iresult.getIssueKey());
          System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.INFO, iresult.getIssueId());
        }
    }
    /**
     * convertStringFormat
     * -Converts date string to proper 
     *  date format for JIRA
     * 
     * @return String
     * @param String
     */
    public static String convertDateFormat(String s) {
        String returnString = s + '.000+0000';
        return returnString;
    }
    /**
     * updateSharedCalendarKey
     * -Updates ecr SCKey (hidden field) to use for 
     *  updates on JIRA ticket
     * 
     * @return void
     * @param String
     * @param Evironment_Change_Request__c
     * @param zsfjira.ZCBeans.IssueUpsertResult
     */
    public static void updateSharedCalendarKey(String key, Environment_Change_Request__c ecr, zsfjira.ZCBeans.IssueUpsertResult iresult) {
        ecr.SCKey__c = iresult.getIssueKey();
        update ecr;
    }
    /**
     * determineJiraCalendar
     * -determine the JIRA calendar field by
     *  using the department on ECR 
     * 
     * @return String (picklist id)
     * @param String
     */
    public static String determineJiraCalendar(String departmentValue) {
        String key = '17900'; //default value (General)
        if(departmentValue.contains('Customer Engineering')) {
          key = '17005'; //CE
        }
        else if(departmentValue.contains('VMS')) {
            key = '17000'; //VMS 
        }
        else if(departmentValue.contains('DevOps')) {
            key = '17012'; //DevOps 
        }
        else if(departmentValue.contains('IT')) {
            key = '17001'; //IT
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, it is likely that something *else* changed. This design works fine until you start using a Batch or Future method to update the records that then trigger this flow. Have you, or another administrator, made any recent changes to your org?

Comment: @sfdcfox I am the only administrator and in terms of this object nothing has changed.